# Making a Clock with AM/PM

Tags: javascript, clock

So I'm making a clock and I'm trying to make it go into AM/PM mode, as of right now it's in military time. I want to make the hours go from 01-12 and minutes go from 00-59 and seconds go from 00-59. Any ideas how to edit this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function startTime() {

  var today = new Date();

  var h = today.getHours();

  var m = today.getMinutes();

  var s = today.getSeconds();

  $('#time').text(h + ":" + m + ":" + s);

  setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);}

startTime();
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If hours is greater than 12, subtract 12.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function startTime() {

  var today = new Date();

  var h = today.getHours();
  if (h >12) { h -=12;} // this 

  var m = today.getMinutes();

  var s = today.getSeconds();

  $('#time').text(h + ":" + m + ":" + s);

  setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);}

startTime();
});
```